# Travel Insurance required for UK citizen applying for an Italian Study Visa D (National Visa)

Tags: united-kingdom, schengen, italy, insurance

I am a UK citizen in the process of applying for an Italian Study Visa D (National Visa) to attend a course on Italian language and culture for 9 months.

I have read the checklist found here:
https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/uk/london/pdf/study-d-italian-lang-or-culture.pdf

It states:

“Medical insurance Must be issued by an insurance company in the UK or in the Schengen area. Must cover at least the first 15 days of stay, must report full name of applicant as per passport, must be valid for the whole Schengen Area, minimum coverage of 30.000 Euro for urgent hospitalization or repatriation expenses. A special insurance policy for student with INA ASSITALIA is available through Universities upon arrival in Italy. If the insurance cover is not specified in the acceptance letter from the Italian university, a declaration in a form of “affidavit” (self-declaration) is required.”

However, the vfs website states something slightly different:

“Travel insurance, which must be issued in UK or in one of the Schengen countries, including every Schengen country covering the entire period of staying in Italy. Health insurance with a minimum coverage of €30,000 for emergency hospital and repatriation expenses. If your current insurance company does not provide such coverage, you are requested to find an international insurance. A special insurance policy for student with INA ASSITALIA is available through Universities upon arrival in Italy. If the insurance cover is not specified in the acceptance letter from the Italian university, a declaration in a form of “affidavit” (self-declaration) is required”

The travel insurance that I currently have covers up to £15,000,000 with a maximum 45 day duration for any one trip. It covers medical emergencies and repatriation.

I wanted to know if this insurance suffices for my application. I am looking to be granted a visa from mid-November to mid-August? I believe that this insurance covers the criteria mentioned in the checklist but does not cover the criteria mentioned on your website (it is not valid for my entire trip, but only 45 days). Could anyone please advise?

Comment: What did VFS say when you asked?

Comment: I have sent an email but they have not replied yet (weekend/bank holiday). I will update when/if they do.

Comment: Remember when you get to Italy you can also register for the SSN https://www.unibo.it/en/services-and-opportunities/health-and-assistance/health-and-medical-assistance-in-bologna-cesena-forli-ravenna-e-rimini/medical-assistance-for-international-students.